# How to access ArangoDB web interface on guest machine

Tags: arangodb

I have ArangoDB installed on a Ubuntu guest machine, and the IP address is 192.168.10.10.  I want to access the web interface from the Ubuntu host, using 192.168.10.10:8529.  How can I do that?

Presumably I need to configure the server to accept remote connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out.

In the `/etc/arangodb3` directory there is `arangod.conf`  In this file, change the endpoint value to the ip address of your machine, in this case 192.168.10.10